# How to get DOM div located somewhere in my app

Tags: reactjs

I want to scroll to the bottom my modal window when some conditions are meet. I want to use something like this:

```
function scrollToBottom() { // in my hook
    const container = document.getElementById('scroll-indicator');
    console.log('container', container); // null
    container.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

and in `parent.parent.parent.parent.parent` component I have:

```
function AFormBody() {
    const { announcement } = useAnnouncementForm();
    return (
        <AnnouncementBody>
            <A/>
            <B/>
            <C/>
            <D/>
            <E/>
            <FComponent/>
            <div id="scroll-indicator" /> // I want to scroll to the bottom of this element
        </AnnouncementBody>
    );
}
```

How to do that? How to find div element in my app, in some other component? Is it possible without passing ref through many child components?

Answer (score 0):

To get access to a react element you can use '`useRef()`', in your case to scroll to the bottom of the div element with the id "scroll-indicator" from a different component in your React application, you can follow these steps:

1-Start by creating a ref in the parent component (AFormBody) and passing it to the child components (FComponent in this case) that may need to scroll. You can do this using React's useRef hook.

2-In the child component (FComponent), you can expose a function that allows you to trigger scrolling when the conditions are met.

3-In your parent component (AFormBody), you can invoke the scroll function on the ref when the conditions are met.

For example

In the parent component (AFormBody):

```
function AFormBody() {
    const scrollRef = useRef(null);

    // Function to scroll to the bottom
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        if (scrollRef.current) {
            scrollRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
    };

    return (
        <AnnouncementBody>
            <A />
            <B />
            <C />
            <D />
            <E />
            <FComponent scrollFunction={scrollToBottom} /> 
            <div id="scroll-indicator" ref={scrollRef} />
        </AnnouncementBody>
    );
}
```

In the child component (FComponent):

```
function FComponent({ scrollFunction }) {
    // Example: When some conditions are met, call the scroll function
    const handleScrollButtonClick = () => {
        // Check your conditions here
        // When conditions are met, call the scroll function
        scrollFunction();
    };

    return (
        <div>
           
            <button onClick={handleScrollButtonClick}>Scroll to Bottom</button>
          
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know but I wanted to avoid passing ref through a couple of child components inside <FComponent /> where there is a function that should triger scrolling in <AFormBody />

Comment: You can use React context or callback props to pass the scroll function down through the component tree.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... I thought that there is some other approach to solve my problem... But it's not...